# How do you deploy ready made AI on chain

Tags: on-chain, bots

I have made a bunch of trading bots using python and tensorflow. How do I deploy this stuff on the chain with Plutus?

Is this the approach taken by Dr Ben Goetzel at SingularityNet or do they run it locally and only use the smart contracts for payment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done that as well for Kucoin Binance etc python is great for backend data analisis... Well.. BlockChain are just transactions...  you should be able to do a BlockChain a transaction from your backend current running bot and give data to your bot from a service like Blockfrost... also.. what you buy and sell should be locked funds in smart contracts, for exqample liquidity pools from sundae Swap...  :)  the buy and sell transactions should be tx with smart contract interactions.

Answer (score 1):

I am not very knowledgeable when it comes to AI, but I'm pretty sure right now it's impossible to have one on-chain for two reasons. First, it would be too computationally heavy, so the current CPU and transactions size limits would be reached. Second, there are no modules that allow this on-chain.

Plutus has a very limited number of types and functions allowed inside the on-chain validator, which certainly doesn't include tensor-flow or any AI related libraries.

Personally, I don't know how Singularity Net is doing, but I suppose they are doing this work off-chain and using oracles to communicate the results on-chain.

If you want to learn about oracles and how to deploy plutus smart-contracts, the best resource right now is the [Plutus Pioneers Program](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-pioneer-program). The third cohort already started, but you can watch the lectures on youtube and do the homework cloning the github repository.

Comment: Im already in the 3rd cohort but they don't seem to cover this.

Comment: They talk about oracles in week06, at least they did in the second cohort

Comment: Thanks that should be this Thursday then